# UWP MVVM Data Binding for dummies (textbox.text from String)

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

Well, having a go at MVVM with UWP template 10. I have read many pages, and although everyone tries to say its really easy, I still can't make it work.

To put it into context, OCR is being run on an image, and I would like the text to be displayed in textbox automatically.

Here is my Model:

```
public class TextProcessing
{
    private string _ocrText;
    public string OcrText
    {
        get { return _ocrText; }
        set
        {
            _ocrText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class ScanPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private TextProcessing _ocrTextVM;
    public ScanPageViewModel()
    {
        _ocrTextVM = new TextProcessing();
    }

    public TextProcessing OcrTextVM
    {
        get { return _ocrTextVM; }
        set {
            _ocrTextVM = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("OcrTextVM");
            }
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Here is my View:

```
<TextBox x:Name="rtbOcr" 
       Text="{Binding OcrTextVM.OcrText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Firstly, that is not working. Could someone try to show where I am going wrong?

Then, the data is coming from a Services file, how would the Services update the value? What would be the correct code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you creating your ViewModel? Where do you set the DataContext of your view?  How do you load the data into your model?  When you say "that is not working", you will need to be more precise about what is not working.

Comment: If you are only changing the `OcrText` property of the `TextProccessing` class then XAML will not notice. With your code you have to set a new instance of the class whenever the data changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is very easy once I manage to understand. Here is the code needed to update a TextBox.Text

In the Models:

```
public class DisplayText : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Text)));
        }
    }
}
```

In the XAML file:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Helper.Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

In the ViewModels:

```
    private DisplayText _helper = new DisplayText();
    public DisplayText Helper
    {
        get { return _helper; }
        set
        {
            _helper = value;
        }
    }
```

Then any mod from the ViewModels:

```
Helper.Text = "Whatever text, or method returning a string";
```

Answer (score 3):

Following code is cite from code.msdn ([How to achieve MVVM design patterns in UWP](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-achieve-MVVM-design-2bb5a580)), it will be helpful for you:

Check you code step by step.

1.ViewModel implemented interface INotifyPropertyChanged,and in property set method invoked PropertyChanged, like this:

```
public sealed class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _productName;
    public string ProductName
    {
        get { return _productName; }
        set
        {
            _productName = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ProductName)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.Initialize you ViewMode in you page, and set DataContext as the ViewMode, like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new MainPageViewModel();
    public MainPage()
    {
        ...
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

3.In you xaml, binding data from viewMode, like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ProductName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="ProductNameTextBox" TextChanged="ProductNameTextBox_TextChanged" />
```

Comment: Thank you for placing the link and explanation :)

Comment: @FranckE So this should be an acceptable answer, it solved your problem:)

Answer (score 2):

Your `OnPropertyChanged` call on OcrTextVM isn't actually called in your case, since you set the value in the constructor to its backing field and bypass the property.

If you set the value via the property, it should work:

```
public ScanPageViewModel()
{
    OcrTextVM = new TextProcessing();
}
```

Of course your view needs to know that `ScanPageViewModel` is its DataContext. Easiest way to do it is in the constructor of the code-behind of your view:

```
public OcrView()
{
    DataContext = new ScanPageViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Assuming your OCR service is returning a new `TextProcessing` object on usage, setting the property of OcrTextVM should suffice:

```
public class ScanPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...       
    private void GetOcrFromService()
    {
        //...
        TextProcessing value = OcrService.Get();
        OcrTextVM = value;  
    }
}
```

On a note, the `OcrTextVM` name doesn't really reflect what the property is doing, since it doesn't look like it's a viewmodel. Consider renaming it.

Comment: That doesn't matter, the property is read anyway if the datacontext is assigned to the newly created viewmodel. His problem's that `TextProcessing` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `TextProcessing.OcrText` should raise `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. My property change was updated using reply 1, and thanks @Haukinger for mentioning that the model should implement the PropertyChanged.